# ComboBox with enumeration and null value

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, nullable, markup-extensions

I have a `ComboBox` that is filled from the values of an enumeration:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{utils:Enumerate {x:Type models:MyEnum}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEnumValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />
```

That uses `utils:Enumerate`, an extension class, to get the values of the enum

```
public sealed class EnumerateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public EnumerateExtension(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var names = Enum.GetNames(Type);
        string[] values = new string[names.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = StringResources.Get(names[i]); //translating the enum value into a readable text
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

That works great and displays all the possible values of an enum in a combobox. It also contains nice readable texts instead of enum values like `NotReleased`.

**But I want the comboxbox to have another value - an empty one. So I can select none of the enum values and deselect previously selected values.**

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `ItemsSource` to a `CompositeCollection` to which you add another `string`:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="...">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
            <s:String>(empty)</s:String>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={utils:Enumerate {x:Type models:MyEnum}}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Replace `System.Runtime` with `mscorlib` in the namespace declaration if you target the .NET Framework.

Or you could add another `string` to the `string[]` returned from your `ProvideValue` method.